# How can I see the output HTML

Tags: python, mechanize

I have this code in python:

```
resp = mechanize.Request(url, data)
cj.add_cookie_header(resp)
res1 = mechanize.urlopen(resp)
```

How can I see the output HTML?

Comment: Run it and look at what the web server gives you?

Comment: Process finished with exit code 0 . But its seems he doesnt make the post and I want to understand why.

Comment: Didn't make the post? Are you taking code example from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225569/how-do-i-get-pythons-mechanize-to-post-an-ajax-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print your response:

```
resp = mechanize.Request(url, data)
cj.add_cookie_header(resp)
res1 = mechanize.urlopen(resp)
print res1.read()
```

Comment: it gives me this: <closeable_response at 0x2d99448L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0000000002D4CC00>... which is far from what i want

Comment: Sorry, didn't copy the last part of code. Edited answer. Check it